# Xamarin iOS auto resize view

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

I'm getting started with Xamarin using Visual Studio 2013 trying to build an iOS app. I have added a launch screen as an XIB file and the default one they give you (as per the tutorials) just has a few labels and when run on the simulator appears fine.

In the designer when I double click on the XIB, the app view to add components to is square, rather than rectangular and vertical as I would expect for an iPhone display. But the default XIB seems to work.

However I have added a UIView and an image to this, told it to fill the width and height, added two labels in the middle and run it. The displayed image is square and goes off the screen of the simulator, as do the labels. It is not automatically resizing to fill the displayed screen as I would hope.

Basically what I want to know is how to start building basic views with resizable components that will work on any device you use. Can anyone please link me to a tutorial for this using Visual Studio Xamarin for iOS as I don't know what to search for.

[What it looks like in designer](https://nzjamesk.tinytake.com/sf/NDYyOTgxXzI0ODcyNzA)

[How it comes out in simulator](https://nzjamesk.tinytake.com/sf/NDYyOTgzXzI0ODcyOTI)